# CPU is hot and CPU fan making very many RPMs and much noise. (CPU fan not listed in speedfan)

Tags: cpu, fan, cooling, temperature, speedfan

On Saturday I replaced the motherboard of my computer because my old motherboard wasn't working anymore. Everything went well, and after some tries my PC was booting and working! I noticed the CPU fan was making a lot of noise. I downloaded cpuid hwmonitor. The CPU was in idle state at 50 - 60 degrees Celsius. And the CPU fan was running at 6700 RPM!

After reapplying thermal paste two times (first time the pea method, then the card method, and then again), the CPU is still hot, but not that hot. If my PC isn't doing anything, my CPU is around 30 - 40 degrees Celsius. But it is getting hot very fast. And the CPU fan runs about 4000 RPM. When I start a program, the fan goes to 6000 RPM.

I downloaded and installed speedfan to try and change the CPU fan's speed. I can see the temperature of my CPU and I can see how fast the fan is going. This fan isn't noted as "CPU fan" or something but as `Fan 1`. The fans are listed like this:

Fan 1: 0 RPM
Fan 2: 0 RPM
Fan 3: 0 RPM
Fan 1: 3500 RPM
Fan 2: 0 RPM
Fan 3: 0 RPM
Fan 4: 0 RPM
Fan 5: 0 RPM
GPU Fan: 1400 RPM

Why all those fans? I have only three fans (CPU, GPU, Power). In speedfan I can control only the GPU fan. And all the others aren't doing anything when I change their values.

**My question:**
How can I make my CPU cooler and make my CPU fan make less noise and RPMs (my computer is clear of dust)? It would also be nice to know why speedfan isn't working.

**Hardware:**

- Motherboard: **Gigabyte GA-970A-UD3** Rev 1.1
- CPU: **AMD FX-8120**
- CPU Fan: **Stock AMD fan**
- GPU: **AMD Radeon HD 6850**

**OS**

- Windows 7

Note: I turned off Smart Fan for speedfan.

**Edit:**
I fixed my problem. I had to replace my amd stock fan with a better one. I bought this one:

http://www.coolermaster.com/cooling/cpu-air-cooler/hyper-212-evo/

Thanks to this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5MVIaUMci4

I want to thank you all for your help and time you spent on helping me! 
 **Thanks!**

Comment: what brand/model of thermal paste?

Comment: My thermal paste's brand is "cooler master"

Comment: @Psycogeek I followed thousands of tutorials about speedfan and i know how to use it(I can control my gpu fan with it). But my cpu fan isn't controllable. As far as i know.

Comment: The program is rather old, and your MB is not old, If there is not a online configuration for it, then it probably is not supported. I can control only my GPU with it too. Not genuine , is only because you replaced the motherboard, that will be fully fixable.  The gigabyte board has thermal fan control, and software for thermal fan control. if either of those were set wrong, it could cause the fans to go wild.  BUT you have said that it is running too hot, so you would want to address that problem , like only, and first.

Comment: When you removed the heatsink the first time did the goop show that it was indeed seated flat , and all evenly squished down?

Comment: @Psycogeek it was evenly squished but it was way to thick and the second time there were quite some airbubbels

Comment: So it could be that one leg of the heatsink just was not down all the way?  I have had that happen before with the stock intel sinks, they are not made for repeated installations. If one side of the cpu is poorly connected to the heat sink it can have the symptoms you indicated in your question. Where it oddly ramps up in temperature, and of course the fans thermally controlled react to that.

Comment: @Psycogeek My cpu's temprature is good in idle but as soon i'm going to run a program irs getting hot very fast. About the thermal fan control. Do i have to download software for it because i only installed drivers for GPU, ethernet and chipset

Comment: @Psycogeek I thinks it's connected well to the cpu.

Comment: The bios will control the fans thermally also when set in there to do that, Added OS software is not required, but could give you more control through fan graphing.  So really you might set the bios correct for thermal control, but there is no reason to install the software until the inital problem is solved at least.  Bios thermal fan control is sufficinet for most uses.

Comment: @Psycogeek Where do i change it? In the bios i can only change the smart fan control for the cpu and wich mode it uses. I got it on auto.

Comment: Auto is fine, Or adjust it for the thermal profiles they show there, which are totally confusing, and just can be simply thought of as going from high reaction to low reaction. any profile will still go RPM crasy when the temps get to like 80*C

Comment: @Psycogeek Low reaction/High reaction where do i change it?

Comment: I do not know how it shows in your bios, vrses here, but most of the high end motherboards have some sort of control of the thermal responce in the bios/uefi,  and usually per fan control area not the main auto (thermal adjusted) or full speed  switch .

Answer (score 3):

From the description it looks like faulty thermal control of the motherboard.
Also, it's not clear for me: did you applied just enough thermal paste or were generous with it?

Solutions I see right now are:

1. Update BIOS of your new MB. Quite often that does the trick on both cpu running too hot and fan not working correctly.
2. If you used a lot of thermal paste it's not good. Paste is not good thermal conductor, you should use as little as possible. In essence, it should fill micro-cracks and other imperfections ion the contact surfaces of both cpu and heatsink. If you did that already (use minimum amount of paste that is), no issue.
3. Fan may have developed a fault. If #1 option is unsuccessful, check with other fan that is known to be working properly (just for tests, so it may be old one). But the cpu is mite too hot, so it may be it's just compensating for that.
4. Are you sure you connected the fan to the cpu_fan connector? I know... But better to make sure. You have quite a lot of connectors there.
5. Make sure you placed and locked the heatsink correctly.

I know most of what I wrote is really basic stuff, but please believe me, I made all of the errors above at one time or the other. If all that fails, it may be that new MB is faulty... I've seen that happen as well.

Windows not genuine is normal after MB replacement - you need to contact Microsoft on that. They will sort it out.

EDIT: afterthought - did you set up BIOS settings of new MB to default? Maybe it's overclocking the CPU on current settings?

Comment: Thanks for your answer i'm going to update my bios although i don't know how. I haven't used much thermal paste and connected it properly to the cpu and pins. Hopefully its fixed after the bios update. Thanks.

Comment: It's not that bad nowadays. Pretty much automatic and if not, it's usually well explained. Go to Gigabyte website, search your mobo and download bios update. And then follow instructions.

Comment: I'm on gigabytes website, my motherboard and then downloads. Download type BIOS. Do i have to flash my bios? Wich on do i have to download? http://www.gigabyte.us/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3907#bios

Comment: Yes, you have to flash BIOS. How to do that: there is a guide above top right corner of the list of versions under the link "Reflash Motherboard BIOS".
I don't understand why the newest version is Beta since Dec'13, but anyway, skip that one. Go for next newest (that would be F8).

Comment: Okay, Is it a big risk to flash your bios? You mean f7? There only is f8f and thats the beta. Thanks

Comment: Right. F7. Sorry. Risk? Some, as always. But not so much as in the old days. Did about a hundred Bios updates, never had failed one. There were some that took hours (4 hours to be exact, but it was specific DELL issue), but not a failure. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: Okay that's nice.

Comment: I've set my bios to default and know my keyboard and mouse aren't working! i can't get in the bios again without keyboard! I don't know why it ain't working! Help!

Comment: Don't panic. With bios default you should have error message saying keyboard not detected on most of the systems. Unplug your mouse and keyboard when computer is powered on and plug them back in. Best into different USB ports. Then go back to BIOS and set it up as you need. If your keyb/mouse are PS-2 connected (small round plug) check if they are seated properly. PS-2 must be reseated with computer OFF (it's not surge-protected, can burn out connector or worse when hot-plugging. And it won't work until rebooted anyway)

Comment: It isn't booting to windows 7 because it asks me if i want to run startup repair. It is asking me this because it turnt the pc off when starting windows. I plugged my keyboard and mouse in another port while the pc is on and it doesn't do anything. B.T.W my mouse and keyboard got usb connection. I think  i setted bios to wrong defaults, i setted it to fail-save defaults...   Also which usb port should i use power usb 3.0 or usb 3.0. When my keyboard and mouse were working, they were plugged in the power usb 3.0

Comment: I got my keyboard and mouse working. i had to use a keyboard with a ps-2 connection and then enable usb 3.0 support. My cpu and fan is still not fixed

Comment: Gotta love legacy hardware support.
Ok, that being said and checked most obvious solutions we need to look again on the hardware. Repeat question: are you sure you placed heatsink properly? Because if everything else works (apparently) correctly, then this would be the next stage.

Comment: I haven't flashed my bios yet. I wanted to be sure it isn't so easy as setting it to the default bios settings

Comment: I wanted to boot my pc but it ain't showing anything on the screen. The screen is okay, i plugged my screen into another pc and it did everything fine. Help?

Comment: The problem was that my gpu wasn't working. I don't know why. I replaced it with another and now it is working.

Comment: I see. Bios setting can also do it in systems allowing overclocking. How did it go? As for the GPU - I may not show anything as after bios default it can switch from PCIe to integrated. You sure gpu is dead? That would be really weird unless it was GPU causing all the trouble (unlikely, but possible). Anything else happened?

Comment: My other gpu is working without problems so i think so. Cpu fan problem isn't fixed cus of the gpu.

Comment: OK. Let's revisit issue. First of all: how the temps are looking when Computer is working (I know of 30-40 in idle, which is normal). How hot it runs when stressed? Also: what was the model of old motherboard? Because it may be that all is ok?

Comment: When i'm not doing anything my cpu even reaches 20 degrees celcius. But the fan still runs at 3000 RPM. Later in the day i can provide the name of my previous motherboard.

Comment: Okay i got speedfan working i made a graph with how hard my fan should run at which degrees. I made a graph that looks good to me. Now i see that my cpu reaches quite some tempratures. Should i buy a new and better fan? Also i lookes good at hwmonitor and it looks like my northbridge also reaches 70 degrees celcius easily. I took it off and reapplyd thermal paste but this doesn't fix it.

Comment: Everything up to 70C is absolutely fine with that CPU. Below 20C at idle is great temp. Normal working conditions would be 50-60C, especially with stock cooling. Unfortunately, AMDs generally run hot. Had it been Intel, then you would not be worried about temp (Intel auto-shuts-down if reaches about 100), AMD can be literally fried. So, your CPU still overheats after above?

Comment: I fixed it! I replaced my stock fan with a cooler master and it's fixed!

Comment: Excellent work!! And thanks for sharing with us the solution. Take care.