# Graphics card suddenly stopped working(Fan is working)

Tags: graphics-card, amd-radeon

I just replaced my motherboard because my other motherboard was broken. I bought a new CPU, ram and motherboard. It all went good until my CPU was getting very hot ([My post](https://superuser.com/questions/911368/cpu-is-hot-and-cpu-fan-making-very-many-rpms-and-much-noise-cpu-fan-not-listed)). Suddenly when i was playing a game, my PC freezed and i turned it off. When i tried to turn it back on my screen was just black. The GPU's fan is working. I tested if my monitor was broken but my monitor was doing fine when i plugged it in another pc. I replaced my GPU with an older one and it was doing fine. Mostly when you try to turn your PC off when you're OS is started it takes some time. When i connect my broken GPU and it's on for 10 mins, i push the power buttonand then it turns off immediately so i think it doesn't start windows when my broken gpu is plugged in. The broken gpu was working fine with my motherboard i had before. I know my gpu is compatible with my new motherboard because my brother had this gpu with motherboard before.

- Broken GPU: **AMD Radeon HD 6850**
- Working GPU(The older one, i
  used for testing): **NVIDIA GeForce GTX 260**
- Motherboard: **Gigabyte GA-970A-UD3** Rev 1.1
- CPU: **AMD FX-8120**
- OS: **Windows 7**

Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit:**

Is it really broken? Is there a change that it is something in my bios settings or something else?

**Edit 2:**

Unfortunatly, my GPU is broken or for some reason my GPU 
starts working after many reseats and power on/off's. This happend to @Psycogeek.

**Thanks for your time and help**

Comment: So, you've established that your GPU is broken. What's your question?

Comment: My question is "Is it really broken? Is there a change that it is something in my bios settings or something else?"

Comment: @joel - BIOS controls your motherboard not the GPU.  Your motherboard will not start if it detects a fault, your GPU is causing a short, because it isn't fully functional.

Comment: ahh i have had times when after removal or moving to a different motherboard the gpu (working a day ago) would just not init, after re-seating it 15 times, checking and re-checking the power (even voltmetering), powering on and off like a crasy person, checking and re-checking everything (yet nothing was wrong) adjusting the bios over and again,  it just decided to fire up and start working again, and for years after, I would so love to know what the problem really was.  Is it possible that it is testing your persistance?  could be, ask the gpu it knows something but wont tell.

Comment: @Psycogeek i hope this happens to me too! :)     Can it be my psu is giving my GPU too less power?

Comment: Possibly could be power ammount or slightly dirty power, it was not for me, that card is still running in another machine. Things I concidered, oxidation of connections, for both the power, and the card edge connects, any dust that from moving it had gotten in there (but i had  cleaned more than once, and tech sprayed the contacts). I got a magnifying glass out to inspect the slot.  but modern pci slots really dig-in so what was the point. Power can have oxidation sluffed off by a few insert and removals, but the fans are running, so it cant be that bad. none of that fixed it, it just started.

Comment: . . . on its own after many more power offs (no changes), and some long times waiting. When I say power off , it was  powering the computer down normal, plus at times  I was also fully removing wall power (switch on psu and plug at times) and waiting here and there, with and without power (anything :-). I wanted some illusive full reset, and or capacitor discharge ,  I knew it was working before, i was sure it was something I was doing wrong,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is just broken. As @Ramhound said in the comments, BIOS will not take care of the internals of the GPU.

The fan working tells you the GPU has power, but no more. It actually neglects issues regarding the GPU not being powered properly. If the GPU was working before and now it makes your motherboard not to start due to problems, I would recommend you to just throw it away as you can make something else to fail by plugging a damaged component.